# pandas get first row in DataFrame with condition

Tags: performance, pandas, ipython, dataframe

I am using Pandas to work with large number of Data. I want to find the **fastest way to get the first row in DataFrame with id**

```
I have 2 DataFrame:

school_detail
school_id detail1 detail2
1         d11     d21 
2         d12     d22 
2         d13     d23
4         d14     d24
...
It has more than 20 million rows

schools
id school_name
1  name1 
2  name2
3  name3
4  name4
...
It has 3 million rows
```

I need to loop through all rows in school_detail to set type for each row.

```
def get_type(s_detail):
   # I need to get school name here to calculate the type so I use
   school = schools[schools.id == s_detail.school_id] # To get school by id

school_detail['type'] = school_detail.apply(lambda x: get_type(x), axis=1)
```

I have use **%prun** to check time for function get school by id. It is about **0.03 sec**

When I run with **10000 rows** of school_detail. It takes **43 sec**.

If I run with 20 mil rows. It may take several hours.

**My questions:**

I want to find the better way to **get school by id** to make it run faster.

The id column is unique. Do pandas use binary search in this column?

Comment: You can try the [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) function rather than testing ``[schools.id == s_detail.school_id]``

Comment: Your get_type function is confusing since it doesn't return anything.  Are you trying to get a dataframe that has schoolid,name,detail1,detail2?

Comment: it seems like all you want is a join

Comment: @cwharland That's true. But in my situation, I use merge function before loop through all rows

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it. It should be fast on large datasets, since it does not use any loop or specific functions. It uses pandas [loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) function.

```py
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data_school_detail = \
"""school_id,detail1,detail2
1,d11,d21
2,d12,d22
2,d13,d23
4,d14,d24"""

data_schools = \
"""id,school_name
1,name1
2,name2
3,name3
4,name4"""

# Creation of the dataframes
school_detail = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_school_detail),sep = ',')
schools       = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_schools),sep = ',', index_col = 0)
# Create a dataframe containing the schools data to be applied on
# dataframe school_detail
res = schools.loc[school_detail['school_id']]
# Reset index with school_detail index
res.index = school_detail.index
# Rename column as presented in the question
res.columns = ['type']
# Add the columns to dataframe school_detail
school_detail = school_detail.join(res)
```

`school_detail` will now contain

```
   school_id detail1 detail2   type
0          1     d11     d21  name1
1          2     d12     d22  name2
2          2     d13     d23  name2
3          4     d14     d24  name4
```

Comment: I do not use .loc function. I merge 2 tables by school_id to get school_name in school_detail. After I change my code, It take only 1/4 time before.